# Find the count of particular non alpha numeric character between the html tags by using PHP preg functions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a part of HTML string like below which I get from web page scraping.

```
$scraping_html = "<html><body>
....
<div id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblHdr'>some text here with &. some text here.</div>
....</body></html>";
```

I want to take count of **&** between the particular div by using PHP. Is it possible to get using any of the PHP preg functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use regular expressions? It's possibly the most difficult way to do it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's not mandatory to use only regular expressions. I believe using regular expression we can achieve it in less coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is getting the text nodes (I assume that's where you're stuck). Depending on how reliable it needs to be you have two alternatives (just sample code, not actually tested):

- Good old [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags):

  ```
  $plain_text = strip_tags($scraping_html);
  ```
- Proper [DOM parser](http://php.net/domdocument):

  ```
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $dom->loadHTML($scraping_html);
  libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $plain_text = '';
  foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
      $plain_text .= $textNode->nodeValue;
  }
  ```

To count, you have e.g. [substr_count()](http://php.net/substr_count).

Comment: @Alvoro Thanks for the multiple solutions. your solutions also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of `&` in the given example, use DOMDocument:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<html><body>
<div id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblHdr'>some text here with &. some text here.</div>
</body></html>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$ele = $dom->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblHdr');
echo substr_count($ele->nodeValue, '&');
```